# After screen turns off, monitor stops responding

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors connected to my computer running Windows 7 SP 1. If I leave my computer for a while, Windows starts the screen saver (which for me is just a black screen). It is not in sleep mode; I have that disabled. However, sometimes when I wake my computer back up, one of the monitors stops responding. I cannot turn it off with the button on the front, nor do any of the other buttons work; it just completely stops responding. The power light is still on on the monitor though. The only way to get it to work again is if I unplug it for a couple of seconds, and plug it back in. It doesn't always happen to the same monitor, I have had it happen both monitors. (Not at the same time, though) It only happens rarely though, maybe once every 2 weeks or so. This is very inconvenient, and I was wondering if anybody knew why this was happening and/or if there is a way to fix it.

**EDIT:** It just happened to me again, but this time both monitors froze simultaneously. I had to unplug them and then plug them back in for them to work again.
Also, in reference to LordLanky's answer, logging in does not solve the problem for me.

P.S. Monitors are different models, but both are from Dell.

Comment: Power button doesn't work? Sounds like a fault with the monitor :(

Comment: That's what I thought, but it has happened on two different monitors so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem - the other panel works, but isn't the main panel, so you can't see what you are doing to unlock.

I believe it's a Windows OS/Driver issue as I can get it to come back to life by doing one of these two things:

1. Remember the steps to unlock. RETURN-->*password*-->RETURN.
2. Connect remotely (have previously installed and activated software).

Both approaches turn the screen back on, and the world is right again.

Similarly random occurrences. Cannot establish the cause either!

ps. Windows 7 Ultimate.